# App starting without splash activity

Tags: java, android, android-activity, splash-screen

I try to put my image when application starting. I have `MainActivity` and make 2nd acivity like this:

```
public class SplashActivity extends Activity
{
    private static final long DELAY = 3000;
    private boolean scheduled = false;
    private Timer splashTimer;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.splash);

        splashTimer = new Timer();
        splashTimer.schedule(new TimerTask()
        {
            @Override
            public void run()
            {
                SplashActivity.this.finish();
                startActivity(new Intent(SplashActivity.this, MainActivity.class));
            }
         }, DELAY);
       scheduled = true;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onDestroy()
    {
        super.onDestroy();
        if (scheduled)
            splashTimer.cancel();
        splashTimer.purge();
    }
}
```

in `SplashAcitivity.xml` i add:

```
android:background="@drawable/my_image"
```

and ofc i copy my_image to folder drawable

Android studio no underlines in my code, seems good, but when i run this app, application work like before, only with MainActivity. No ideas from me how to fix it.

Comment: SplashActivity.this.finish(); call this after startActivity and have you set splashactivity to be launcher in manifest or not?

Answer (score 0):

you edit the AndroidManifedst to run the splashScreen before the MainActivity?

you need to change were you have

```
<activity
    android:name=".MainActivity"
    android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
     </intent-filter>
</activity>
```

you need to change

```
<category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
```

to

```
<category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
```

and in the SplashScreen put the

```
<category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
```

Comment: it is only work when i put also in SplashScreen `<action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />` is it normal ?

Comment: yes, you need to copy the acivity code, but change the MainActivity to Default and set the SplashScreen as Launcher